# How crop image by diagonally?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want crop image by diagonally. My image dimension 1000x1000. I create blank image and try add cropped part to it. But output.png is empty.

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap("input.png");
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();   

Point[] P = new Point[]
{
   new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 },
   new Point { X = 1000, Y = 0 },
   new Point { X = 0, Y = 1000 }
};

gp.AddPolygon(P.ToArray());       

using (Bitmap bmp0 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("output.png"))
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
{
  G.Clip = new Region(gp);   
  G.DrawImage(bmp0, 0, 0);   
  G.Save();
}
gp.Dispose();
```

[image]

Comment: You are not saving the bitmap, you are 'saving' the graphics object. Use `bmp1.Save("d:\\output2.png", ImageFormat.Png);` - Note that you can't overwrite the original as it is still in use!!

Comment: _I create blank image_ Not really.

Comment: @Taw not working.

Comment: To actually create a blank image use `using (Bitmap bmp0 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(filename))
            using (Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(bmp0.Width, bmp0.Height))` - _not working_ Is an extremly unhelpful statement. My suggestion works fine here; try again!!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xs28rDau whats incorrect here @TaW

Comment: @TaW in output i see blank image

Comment: You are drawing a blank onto the same blank. You need to use the input image; sorry I got the names wrong, do use your own names.. - In my comment bmp0 is the input image. Best call things by a good name like bmpIn and bmpOut :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nested for loop.
pseudo code can be like this:

```
for(int i=1; i<=1000;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<= i;i++){
        newImage[i][j] = image[i][j];
    }
}
```